# Элемент "ZipFile" не существует в текущем контексте

Tags: c#

Как подключить сборку `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно установить расширение Nuget для VS, затем в свойствах проекта подключить пакет Nuget `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` найдя его в сети.